# iOS automation with Appium

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I am writing my 1st automation code for iOS device and i am seeing the following error message that I do not know how to debug..

*** Error Message ***

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 602.97 seconds

Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'

System info: host: 'Husky-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '10.131.32.153', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.8.0_05'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)

at com.husky.test1.Appium_take1.main(Appium_take1.java:43)

*****  End of Error Message ******
```

I am using Appium 1.2 and here is my code:

*** Code ***

```
package com.husky.test1;


import java.io.File;

import java.net.URL;

import java.util.List;



import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import org.testng.Assert;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;



import java.net.MalformedURLException;






public class Appium_test1 {

    public static void main(String... args){

        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone");

        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("version", "7.1");

        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/cutehusky/Downloads/Payload2/test.app");

        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone");       

        URL url = null;

        WebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url,desiredCapabilities);

        By b = By.xpath("UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[5]/UIAStaticText[1]");

        WebElement we = remoteWebDriver.findElement(b);

        we.click();

    }

}
```

**** End of Automation Code ****

Explain:

I am trying to launch my test app under "/Users/cutehusky/Downloads/Payload2/test.app", find a button base on its xpath (UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[5]/UIAStaticText[1]) and click on it.

Thats all I am looking to accomplish at the moment, please help me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the following tells you everything you need to know:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

When you begin your test, you need to make sure the following things aren't running:

- Simulator
- Instruments

Appium sometimes gets into a state where it thinks the Simulator is running, but it's not. This is solved by restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remote webdriver use below code

```
            protected static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
            driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(url, dCapabilities);
```

and try to run if it works